# Display a ListView row in a label

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView in WPF that is getting data from a database. I want it that, when i have a column selected, and press a button, it will display a row as label.content. Here's what I have this far but it wont work(i removed some items like height etc from it atm):

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1}" Header="Item1"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2}" Header="Item2"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item3}" Header="Item3"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

And then in the code behind part:

```
    DataRowView dataRow;
    int indexInt;

    indexInt = listView.SelectedIndex;
    dataRow = listView.Items.GetItemAt(indexInt) as DataRowView;

    if(dataRow!=null)
    {
         labelOne.Content = (dataRow["Item2"]);
    }
```

If i remove the datarow!=null check, it will display this error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Can anyone help me fix this or should I approach it in another way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an MVVM approach:

-->  your `ListView`'s `ItemsSource` property should be bound to the collection being displayed.
--> (**OPTIONAL**)  your `ListView`'s `SelectedValue` property should be bound to a property in your ViewModel, let's call it `CurrentRow`.
-->  `labelOne`'s `Content` property should be bound to `CurrentRow` (or `listView.SelectedValue.Item2` if you didn't do the optional step)

And you won't have to tinker with UI elements from code behind anymore (which is usually a sign of bad practice).
In fact, you probably won't need to name your controls anymore either.

It should look like this:

```
<Label name="labelOne" Content="{Binding SelectedValue.Item2, ElementName=listView}" />
<ListView x:Name="listView" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item1}" Header="Item1"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item2}" Header="Item2"/>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Item3}" Header="Item3"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
```

Comment: I just have to say, wow... This was so easy and it took me about 4 hours of googling(with trying different methods) and when i finally came here, i got the answer and its that simple!:)
Thank you a lot!